# Passthrough Geometry Shader

Tags: geometry, glsl, shader

I'm trying to build a simple passthrough **geometry shader**, but 
I cant make it work with

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, fooSize, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

but it does work with

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, foo_INDEX);.
```

the geometry shader is..

```
#version 400
#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 : enable

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

void main() {
  for(int i = 0; i <  gl_VerticesIn; i++) {
    gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[i];
    EmitVertex();
  }
  EndPrimitive();
}
```

So, someone has any idea why this geometry shader works with drawArrays and doesnt work with drawElements? Please.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense without some idea of *what* "doesnt work" about it.

Answer (score 12):

You have written a very confused and confusing geometry shader.

Your first line indicates that you're using GLSL version 4.00. This language has geometry shaders as a core feature; no extensions required. Your second line then enables the EXT_geometry_shader4 *extension*.

The problem comes from the fact that core geometry shaders and EXT_geometry_shader4 are *very different things*.

For example, there is no `gl_VerticesIn` in core geometry shaders. The number of vertices you get is defined by your `layout() in;` statement. You used `triangles`, so the answer is 3. You can also find it by using `gl_in.length()`, where `gl_in` is an interface block array containing the default vertex input values. Similarly, `gl_PositionIn` doesn't exist in core geometry shaders; you use `gl_in[index].gl_Position`.

So your geometry shaders code seems to be designed for EXT_geometry_shader4... except for these lines:

```
layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;
```

These are pure core geometry shaders; in EXT_geometry_shader4, these parameters are specified at link time in OpenGL code, not in the shader itself.

So you've thoroughly confused the compiler by having half of it use the EXT version and half use the core version.

A proper core version of what you're trying to do would be this:

```
#version 400

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

void main() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // You used triangles, so it's always 3
    gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
  }
  EndPrimitive();
}
```

I have no idea if this will fix your problem, but these *are* problems with your shader.

Comment: Thank you. (I'm noob with geometry shaders. ) Now I'm using only that pure core syntax,
But my problem remains.
It works fine with **glDrawArray** and does **not** work with **glDrawElements** It returns "Invalid operation" as if the shader mode was incompatible with the draw mode (both are triangles) =/

Comment: @LennaMaule And you're sure it really is caused by the shader. Did you try it without the geometry shader?